# Bootstrap input with label button to datapicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have html with label, input and button to datapicker. I have a problem, because my datapicker button is little above an input. Below I show my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-5 form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="CreatedFrom">Created From</label>
                <input id = "CreatedFrom" type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="change($event,'dt')" placeholder="Generated From" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="caseFilter.dateFrom" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptionsDt" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Effect is: [image]

How could I obtain both input and button for the datapicker both in one line? I would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 form-group">
    <label for="CreatedFrom">Created From</label>
    <div class="input-group">        
        <input id = "CreatedFrom" type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="change($event,'dt')" placeholder="Generated From" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="caseFilter.dateFrom" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptionsDt" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:  `top:13px;` as a value to the whole button element that use for the calendar.

Check out this JS Fiddle: [AnswerFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37181/)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting out the label tag from the input.input-group:

```
<div class="col-md-5 form-group">
  <label for="CreatedFrom">Created From</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id = "CreatedFrom" type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="change($event,'dt')" placeholder="Generated From" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="caseFilter.dateFrom" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptionsDt" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap 3 use .input-append class. Something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-5 form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="CreatedFrom">Created From</label>
            <div class="input-append">
                <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text">
                <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Bootstrap input-groupe](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/)